# How to install Wordpress 4.9 on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I deployed Wordpress on Google Cloud via Click-to-Deploy VM, but it was in the latest version of Wordpress.

How can I install Wordpress 4.99?

I can't find any Marketplace solutions for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not tech support for Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [**WP Downgrade | Specific Core Version**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-downgrade/) plugin you can downgrade to any version of WordPress installation.